Detect function calls originating from multi-line strings
I would like to determine whether a function is called from inside a multi-line string (during string interpolation).
Here is a test example for such a function:
s = f"""\
{inside_multiline_string()}"""
assert s == "True"

assert not inside_multiline_string()

Ideally this would work not by manually parsing the source code, but rather rely on some built-in introspection capability of Python. So that it works robustly.
Additionally it should work transitively, i.e. if the parent call is inside a multi-line string, it should still be marked as inside a multi-line string.
Here is a more complicated test example
def foo():
    return inside_multiline_string()

def bar():
    return foo()

s = f"""\
{bar()}"""
assert s == "True"


Why do you need to know that?

You can use a Use of a Decorator that can be applied to any function to check if it's being called from inside a multi-line string.
import inspect

def is_called_from_multiline_string(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        try:
            code = inspect.getsourcelines(frame)[0]
            if any(line.strip().startswith(('"""', "'''")) for line in code):
                return f"True"
        finally:
            del frame

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@is_called_from_multiline_string
def inside_multiline_string():
    return "False"

s = f"""\
{inside_multiline_string()}"""
assert s == "True"

assert inside_multiline_string() == "False"

@is_called_from_multiline_string
def foo():
    return inside_multiline_string()

@is_called_from_multiline_string
def bar():
    return foo()

s = f"""\
{bar()}"""
assert s == "True"

A nicer and simpler approch would be uisng sys._getframe(1) to get the frame object of the caller, which is the function that called inside_multiline_string() If we find any string constants that contain a newline character ('\n'), we assume that the function was called from within a multi-line string
import sys

def inside_multiline_string():
    
    frame = sys._getframe(1)

    # Check if the code in the current frame is a multi-line string
    code = frame.f_code.co_consts
    for const in code:
        if isinstance(const, str) and '\n' in const:
            return True

    return False


s = f"""\
{inside_multiline_string()}"""
assert s == "True"

assert not inside_multiline_string()

def foo():
    return inside_multiline_string()

def bar():
    return foo()

s = f"""\
{bar()}"""
assert s == "True"

